# How can I plot graphs of CP-ABE scheme using charm crypto?

Tags: pairings, abe

Can I use **charm crypto** tool to run it over my datasets for **CPABE** *scheme* and plot graphs using its *Benchmark*ing tool ?
Or, how can I use **Charm Crypto** tool with **CPABE toolkit** ?

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, you can use charm as a benchmarking tool for bandwidth performance, for CP-ABE, but not for computational performance, as charm is basically python over the PBC-library (https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/). We used charm for Dual-Policy ABE evaluation, but for subjective policies that becomes identical to CP-ABE, see http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/MILCOM.2016.7795382.

2) Bethencourt's cpabe toolkit and charm are actually parallel frameworks. You probably *could* tweak charm to use PBC via the cpabe toolkit, but there's no reason, as you can use PBC directly from charm as well (easier, in my opinion)

Comment: Can you explain me briefly how did you use charm for the benchmarking.
**link to any demonstration could help me a lot

Comment: Charm seems to be discussed in more detail in the stackoverflow, just google "Charm crypto site:stackoverflow.com", or add "cpabe" as a search term if too many hits (to have a detailed look at source code level). Our aims can be found from the DOI-link above (but no source code).